# delete whitespace at the end of number format

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have several line contains number like:

XXXXXX.XXX (this number ended by whitespace.)

How can I delete whitespace at the end of number format using sed?
Thank for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/\s*$//' in > out
```

removes any trailing spaces

```
sed -re 's/^([0-9\.]+)\s*$/\1/' in > out
```

removes trailing spaces only on line beginning with a combination of digits and dot

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\s\+$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//' file
```